# Saving oversampled dataset as csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, resampling, smote

I am new to Python and apologize in advance, if it is too simple. Cannot find anything and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654649/how-to-save-synthetic-dataset-in-csv-file-using-smote) did not help.

My code is

```
# Split data
y = starbucks_smote.iloc[:, -1]
X = starbucks_smote.drop('label', axis = 1)

# Count labels by type
counter = Counter(y)
print(counter)
Counter({0: 9634, 1: 2895})

# Transform the dataset
oversample = SMOTE()
X, y = oversample.fit_resample(X, y)

# Print the oversampled dataset
counter = Counter(y)
print(counter)
Counter({0: 9634, 1: 9634})
```

How to save the oversampled dataset for future work?

I tried

```
data_res = np.concatenate((X, y), axis = 1)
data_res.to_csv('sample_smote.csv')
```

Got an error

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, 
but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: What is result or error after trying to save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create dataframe:

```
data_res = pd.DataFrame(X)
data_res['y'] = y
```

and then save `data_res` to CSV.

Solution based on concatenation od `numpy.arrays` is also possible, but [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) is needed to make dimensions compliant:

```
data_res = np.concatenate((X, np.vstack(y)), axis = 1)
data_res = pd.DataFrame(data_res)
```