# After SMOTE how to export to a CSV file

Tags: python, smote

I ran the following Python code to take care of my imbalanced data problem. I used the SMOTE function. I am not sure how I would see and export(as an excel file to my desktop)"resample data set" (1: 860 to 0:860). Because I want to take that excel file and process it using another application.Any help is much appreciated

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

smote = SMOTE()

x_smote , y_smote = smote.fit_sample(x, y)

print('Original dataset:', Counter(y))

print('Resample dataset:', Counter(y_smote)
```

**Output**

Original dataset shape Counter({1: 860, 0: 483})

Resample dataset shape Counter({1: 860, 0: 860})

Comment: This question may be similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654649/how-to-save-synthetic-dataset-in-csv-file-using-smote

Answer (score 2):

The variable `y` and `y_smote` are dataFrame, so to convert them to .csv use

```
y.to_csv("file1.csv")
y_smote.to_csv("file2.csv")
```

Locate the files named `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` in your root directory

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I ran it for the x values as well. Thanks, it works, but shouldn't I see the values for the predictors too (with this, I only see the output). I will be using SVM will need the values for the predictors too.

Comment: values of the predictors? Can you rephrase

Comment: yes, i have 37 predictors and I am trying to see the value of those predictors after SMOTE. I used x_smote.to_csv("file3.csv") to retrieve them. I hope I did it right